# How to put CRLF into ms word DOCVARIABLE or DOCPROPERTY

Tags: ms-word, docvariable

Is there any way to create (and display) multi-lined `DOCVARIABLE` *without* VBA?
I.e. "One\r\nTwo\r\nThree" renders into

`One
Two
Three`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
{ DOCVARIABLE  TestVar  \* MERGEFORMAT }


Sub DocVars()
    Dim arr As Variant, joinSting As String
    arr = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")
    joinSting = Join(arr, vbNewLine)
    ActiveDocument.Variables("TestVar").Value = joinSting
End Sub
```

[image: Output:]

Comment: thx! it works, but creates new paragraphs, not new lines inside paragraph
anyway, i didn't going to use VBA - have corrected original post

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use `DOCVARIABLE` without `VBA`. Please refer this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-DocVariable-field-32a81e22-c5c1-4b16-8097-f0de851db67c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: DOCPROPERTY is ok for me. Thank you